# how to handle formset in django post view. error: ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with

Tags: django-forms, formset

My template is, my context variable is zipped into three different variables

```
{% extends "question/base_home.html" %}
{% load staticfiles%}
{% block questions %}
{% for result, prev_answers, answerForm in context.zipped_results%}
<form action="/q/answer/" method="post" style="display:none;"  class="answer_form" >
{% csrf_token %}
{% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
{# below code did not work #}
{{ context.zipped_results.2.management_form }}    
{% endif %}
{# neither this #}
{# {{ context.zipped_results.2.management_form }} #}
{# this worked by but it disturbs the way I display forms #}
{# {{ context.answersFormset}} #}
{{ answerForm.as_p }}
{# {{ answerForm.management_form }} #}
<input type="hidden" name="q_id_a" id="q_id_a" value="{{ result.object.id }}">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock questions %}
```

and my post view is

```
def answer(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=AnswerForm(request.POST)
        answerFormset=formset_factory(AnswerForm)
        formset=answerFormset(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                print form
                answer=form.cleaned_data['answer']
                q_id=request.POST.get("q_id_a", "")
                a=Answers.objects.create(questions_id=q_id,answer=answer,    time_stamp=datetime.datetime.now(), upvote=0, downvote=0)
            return HttpResponse("your answer is posted succesfully")
else:
            return HttpResponse("somethign went wrong while posting the answer")
```

I followed the documentation mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates) but i always end up with this error. The only case when I am not getting this error is when i use `{{ context.zipped_results.2 }}`, as per the document when formset is displayed this say management_form need not be used in template. I think the issue is with the management_form. I am not able to figure out how to use it.

I am zipping the results in context variable as `context={'results':results, 'form':form, 'zipped_results':zipped_results, 'answersFormset':answersFormset}`